# How to make a generic typescript service available throughout a module in angular7?

Tags: typescript, servicestack, angular7

I would like

> _findEpisodeService

to be available throughout my app.module. So I need to provide it in the providers array of @NgModule of my app.module. The problem is I'm not sure how to do it. Please help!

```
// Generic service
export class ServicestackService<T> {
  constructor(private _auth: AuthenticationService, private _router: Router) {
    this._client.onAuthenticationRequired = this.onAuthenticationRequired;
  }
}

// service.ts
const req = new FindEpisode();
const _findEpisodeService = new ServicestackService<FindEpisode>(this.auth, this.router);

// App.module.ts
@NgModule({
providers: [
 {provide: JsonServiceClient, useValue: new JsonServiceClient('/')}
 ],
})
```